# How to properly set and test Hapi domain and subdomain?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm currently updating a [small library](https://github.com/iwatakeshi/gengojs-accept) that I've made for parsing the locale from a request object. It's currently works with Express and Koa but I'm trying to get it to work with Hapi.

For tests, I'm using Mocha and Hapi's `inject` method as described in their docs. I've also looked in their docs for setting the server's [properties](http://hapijs.com/api#server-properties), but I do not find an example of setting a domain such as `locahost.en` or even subdomains such as `en.localhost.com`.

Currently, I have my test setup like the following:

```
var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
    //is this correct?
    uri:'localhost.en:3000',
    port: 3000
});

var handler = function(request, reply) {
    //return the parsed locale {String}
    return reply(accept(request, {
           supported: ['en']
    }).getFromDomain());
 };

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: handler
});
server.start(function() {});
```

where `inject` is set like this:

```
server.inject({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    headers: {
        'Accept-Language': 'ja',
        'Set-Cookie': 'mycookie=test'
     }}, function(res) {
        assert.strictEqual(res.result, 'en');
        done();
});
```

How would I be able to set the domain and subdomain in the server properties? Is there a plugin that does that? Also, how could I get/parse the domain and subdomains from `request`? I'm assuming I could get the domain from `hostname` but how about the subdomain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, Hapi will listen on a port on a network interface to all requests regardless of the domain (indicated by the value of the `host` header). If you want to get the value of the host header for a request, you can simply check `request.headers.host`.

If you just want to check the parsed hostname (domain), you can check `request.info.hostname`

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function(request, reply) {

        var hostname = request.info.hostname;    

        reply('Ok');
     }
});
```

If you want to restrict the hostnames allowed for a route (or a plugin), you can set the `vhost` option.

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    vhost: ['en.example.com'],
    handler: function(request, reply) {

        reply('Ok');
     }
});
```

To test different vhosts with `server.inject`, you can just include an explicit host header

```
server.inject({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    headers: {
        'Set-Cookie': 'mycookie=test',
     }}, function(res) {

        Assert(res.statusCode === 404);    // 404 because not en.example.com
});

server.inject({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    headers: {
        'Set-Cookie': 'mycookie=test',
        'Host': 'en.example.com'
     }}, function(res) {

        Assert(res.statusCode === 200);    // 200 because en.example.com
});
```

Comment: Awesome it worked plus I never thought I'd get a reply from someone who writes [great blogs](http://matt-harrison.com/moving-from-express-to-hapi-js/)! Thanks!